# Program received signal: “0”

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am working on page control to show some buttons on each page & to capture the image o it. But, after capturing 10-12 images. I am getting this error -Program received signal:  “0” and my application crashed. I know its a memory issue. but i don't know which object is creating problem. Anyone has any solution for this issue.

Thanks
nitesh

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone, it can indicate that you ran out of memory. Use the "Run with Performance Tool" -> "Leaks" in Xcode to monitor memory usages and for catching memory leaks. On the older 3G iPhone models, anything over 30MB is a candidate for running into out of memory issues. If your memory is heavily fragmented, this can occur more with lower memory usage.

Answer (score -1):

I never developed for I-phone, but, yes, it is obvious that you have a null-pointer problem.

Surely your IDE has a debugger? If not, ditch it and get one that has. Use the debugger and step though until "crash! bang! fireworks"' (or run until then and look at the call stack) to find the offending line.

It will then be be obvious what the offending variable is. The rest is left as an exercise for Sherlock Holmes ^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h the reader ...